# IE Crashes on loading a page with javascript code from a page which already has a javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an index.html page with Javascript function to create tabs :

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

The same index.html file has links to 2 kinds of pages:

1. One which redirect to a page which again has the same JavaScript function for tabs.
2. Other redirects to a page with no JavaScript function for tabs.

The index.html page with link to a page with JavaScript function crashes on IE when clicked. Works without any issues on Chrome and Firefox. However the link (on index.html) to the page without JavaScript function works without any issues. The problem I am facing is because of having the similar JavaScript function for creating tabs on 2 pages which are linked to one another and that could be causing a conflict.

Please let me know how to go about fixing this issue.

Thanks

I wouldn't be able to post all my code as it is proprietary. However I am posting the relevant code below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <a name='top'></a>
    <h3>First Tab</h3>
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td class='summary' bgcolor='#ffffcc'>&abcd;</td>
            <th class='summary' align='center'><a title='Tue Jun 25 05:50:49           
   2013' href='test.php?p=XYZ'>XYZ</a></th>
    </tr>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    <a name='top'></a>
    <h3>Second Tab</h3>
    <table border='1'>
            <td class='summary' bgcolor='#ffffcc'>&abcd;</td>
            <th class='summary' align='center'><a title='Tue Jun 25 05:50:49 
    2013' href='test.php?p=ABC'>ABC</a></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

'test.php?p=XYZ' is the page which again has javascript code for tabs --> the page which does not load and crash on IE, loads without issue on chrome and firefox.
'test.php?p=ABC' is the page which does not have any javascript code for tabs --> the page loads without any issues on any`enter code here` browser.

```
/*Sample code of the page that crashes, it crashes even when you access the link  
directly*/
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<a name='top'></a>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td class='summary' bgcolor='#ffffcc'>&abcd;</td>
            <th>2013-06-26</th>
            <th>2013-06-19</th>
            <th>2013-06-12</th>
            <th>2013-06-05</th>
            <th>&abcd;</th>
    <th>&abcd;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#ffffcc'>Display</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td><a href='some_link'>Sorted List</a></td>
    <td><a href='Another_link'>hyperlink</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
<a name='top'></a>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td class='summary' bgcolor='#ffffcc'>&abcd;</td>
            <th>2013-06-26</th>
            <th>2013-06-19</th>
            <th>2013-06-12</th>
            <th>2013-06-05</th>
            <th>&abcd;</th>
    <th>&abcd;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#ffffcc'>Display</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td align='right'>14</td>
            <td><a href='some_link'>Sorted List</a></td>
    <td><a href='Another_link'>hyperlink</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</div>
</body>enter code here
```

Comment: What happens if you open the crashing page directly (not via a link)? I assume it will still crash the browser...

Comment: From what you explain there should be no problem because the pages would be independent of each other. Can you post your HTML for us to have a look?

Comment: Are these links to completely separate pages or is it a single page application with links loading different views within the same page?

Comment: what is `&abcd;`? that looks actually like an entity, but is not a known one. you should escape it like `&amp;abcd;` or remove it to try; probably IE's JScript is broken by the `tabs` plugin + an undefined entity...? what ie version do you use?

Comment: Please post something from the page which _is_ crashing the browser. It is most likely that the other page is wrong, there is (almost) nothing to fix on this one. You also said in a comment that it is crashing if you open it directly...

Comment: I have attached the code for the page that crashes(when accessed from the first page as well as access it directly).

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs twice and breaks the page, use an indicator to avoid the problem:

```
$(function() {
    var $tabs = $('#tabs'),
    done = $tabs.data('done');

    if (!done) {
        $tabs.tabs();
        $tabs.data('done',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I use this if my javascript code exists in one page and same javascript code exists in another page and the link to the second page is present in the first page?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using .onload or .ready? Perhaps delaying the function may eradicate the issue?

Comment: If I load the crashing page directly, it crashes again. No, I am not using .onload or .ready.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to post all my code as it is proprietary. However I am posting the relevant code below:

Comment: It is safe to say that the posted code is not crashing any browsers. The html is not valid as you are not opening a tr in the 2nd table. Also you have to call the `.tabs()` in `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ //code here });</script>` block which is right before the `</body>` element.